How can you export an outlook email group to gmail via webbrowser
For some society I made an E-mail group in outlook looking like this "xxxx12345@groups.outlook.com".
I am leaving the society and my role in it is now managed by some guy which happen to use Gmail.
He can send Emails to this mail group, that works. But we need him to be able to manage this group.
Besides manually copy pasting each and every single E-mail address in an E-mail and send it to him, I was wondering if there is an easy way to give him my E-mail group so he can add and remove people.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Exporting  Outlook email groups to Gmail is easy via your web browser. Sign in to Outlook.com, select the contacts you need, and export them to a CSV file. Then log in to Gmail, import the CSV file, and voila. Your Outlook groups will be added to Gmail, allowing for seamless email communication across platforms.
